# R calculate mean square for all sub groups in a subset

Tags: r, mean-square-error

how do I calculate the mean square of all 2019_Preston_STD,2019_Preston_V1,2019_Preston_V2 etc using the Value column, then the adjmth1, adjmth3 columns

```
structure(list(IDX = c("2019_Preston_STD", "2019_Preston_V1", 
"2019_Preston_V2", "2019_Preston_V3", "2019_Preston_W1", "2019_Preston_W2"
), Value = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 5L), adjmth1 = c(2.87777777777778, 
1.85555555555556, 2.01111111111111, 1.77777777777778, 3.62222222222222, 
4.45555555555556), adjmth3 = c(2.9328763348507, 2.08651828334684, 
2.80282946626847, 2.15028039284054, 2.68766916156347, 4.51425274916654
), adjmth13 = c(2.81065411262847, 1.82585524933201, 1.81394057737959, 
1.40785681078568, 3.30989138378569, 4.7301083495049)), row.names = 29:34, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: sounds like summarizing by group, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/11562656/3358272, it's likely a dupe of that

Comment: OK I will check that out Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This task can be done in many ways, as shown in the link that @r2evans pointed out. My favorite one is `dplyr` using `summarize(across()` because to me its syntax is easy to understand and easy to apply to many columns. It also presents the resulted numbers in nice format.

For example, from `iris` data I want to get the arithmetic `mean` of `Sepal.Length`, `Petal.Length`, and `Petal.Width` for each of species : setosa, versicolor, and virginica. Here is the head of the data:

```
head(iris)
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

And here is how to get the mean in each species:

```
iris %>% group_by(Species) %>% 
         summarize(across(c(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, Petal.Width), mean))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Species    Sepal.Length Petal.Length Petal.Width
# <fct>             <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1 setosa             5.01         1.46       0.246
# 2 versicolor         5.94         4.26       1.33 
# 3 virginica          6.59         5.55       2.03
```

As for your task, first you need to define the function for the *mean square* (because its definition slightly varies in some references). Then, you apply it to your data frame using `summarize(across())`.

For example, you define the mean square function as follows:

```
meansq <- function(x) sum((x-mean(x))^2)/(length(x)-1)
```

*Note: This definition requires that length(x) doesn't equal 1, or otherwise NaN will be produced.*

You can apply it to your data frame `newdata` as follows:

```
newdata %>% group_by(IDX) %>% 
            summarize(across(c(Value, adjmth1, adjmth3), meansq)
```

Comment: Thanks Abdur , that will do the trick!